# pandas dataframe - sum and count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a df that has this:

| ID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1/2/23 | 12 |
| 5678 | 1/2/23 | 34 |
| 5678 | 1/2/23 | 56 |
| 9012 | 1/2/23 | 70 |

I am trying to get the sum of 'Amount' and the count of 'Date':

| ID | Count(Date) | Sum(Amount) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 12 |
| 5678 | 2 | 90 |
| 9012 | 1 | 70 |

I have tried varies groupby's, agg's, and similar but can't seem to figure it out.

How do I do this?

Comment: `df.groupby("ID").agg({"Date":"count", "Amount":"sum"})`

Comment: thanks andrej. just fyi, i tried many of the solutions in the posted answer and 1 did not work for me and another threw an error. your solution above does work. perhaps i had mistyped something